# Does Roku provide speech to text?

Tags: roku

I am developing a roku tv app and want to integrate speech to text in it. does roku provide speech to text since it provides vice versa so hoping that there is other way round as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the form you expect it (voice recognition) - but rOS 7.6 just added a [roMicrophone](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roMicrophone) API for access to the remote mic. After that you'd have to use the recording with a (cloud-based) voice recognition service of your own

Answer (score 1):

As [Nas Banov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226086/nas-banov) mentioned, you can use [roMicrophone](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roMicrophone) to capture audio and then use a cloud-based API to convert that audio to text.
Google Cloud has an awesome Speech-to-Text API, I recently did a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@alejandrocotilla/speech-recognition-on-roku-using-google-cloud-speech-to-text-api-ac79bb944986) on how to integrate this API on Roku.
You can also check out a demo app [here](https://github.com/acotilla91/Google-STT-Roku-Demo).